# Naming conventions and ReSharper and application-based acronyms

Tags: c#, resharper, naming-conventions

Does anyone have insight to ReSharper Ultimate 9.1 (2015) and handling naming conventions.  I don't want to turn them off and DO prefer context of using CamelCasing via the different versions starting with upper or lower with respect to scope.  All that is no problem.

Where I have a problem is working with application-based acronyms.  Say I have a "THING" acronym in my app, and in a table, I have a "THAT" acronym.  So if I want any variables within different scopes, things like

```
private _myTHINGs[]
public MyTHINGs[]
private _myTHING
public MyTHING
```

(and similar with the "THAT" acronym),

I am constantly getting nagged about naming conventions and it wants to keep changing them to something like

```
private _myThinGs[]
public MyThinGs[]
private _myThinG
public MyThinG
```

or similar.  In some places, during the context-sensitive light-bulb how do I want to handle, it has offered instances of adding the acronym to the global settings for the solution and in some places it appears to work, but in others, it doesn't and I just dont want to have a ton of comments of

```
// ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Resharper 7.3 but I can't imagine it's changed.

Go to Resharper Options via the menu bar, select C#, C# Naming Style, and then click Advanced Settings.  At the bottom of this dialog, add in your company-specific abbreviations (separated by spaces).

Comment: Correct on where I did see them, but its with the naming convention rules on being applied.  Its like it doesn't like these acronyms respected as a leading, trailing or in-the-middle.  Not all the time, but I can't put my finger on why sometimes yes, sometimes not.

Comment: Hmmm, could you then be more specific in your question?  Show some examples of names and the error you get that you don't like.